# Navigating To All Tenant Routes Redirects Back To "/" Except Register Route - hyn/multitenant

Tags: php, multi-tenant, laravel-8

I can't go to any routes inside tenants.php besides register. It always redirects back to home.
Here's my tenants route file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// This if for the Tenant Route

Route::view('/', 'tenant');

Route::view('/login', 'tenant'); // redirects back to '/'
Route::view('/register', 'tenant'); // works
Route::view('/admin', 'tenant'); // redirects back to '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `RouteServiceProvider`, you will find the answer to your enigma here:

`public const HOME = '/home';`